# No funciona take() al hacer una petición http en Angular

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, rxjs

Estoy comenzando con Angular y al hacer una llamada a una Api a través de HttpClient y quiero usar el operador take de Rxjs para devolver los 4 primeros resultados, éste es el código de la llamada:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http
        .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .pipe(
          take(4)
        ).subscribe(val => console.log('users list', val));
}
```

Sin embargo me devuelve todos los datos de la respuesta, en este caso quiero solo los 4 primeros usuarios y no todos los del Json.

He probado otros operadores como tap para mostrar un mensaje y no entiendo porque take() y otros operadores para filtrar o transformar los datos no me funciona ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Espero vuestra ayuda, he probado de varias maneras y sigue sin funcionar.

Gracias por anticipado :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu código se está aplicando `take()` al observable de la petición http y no al arreglo que se desea filtrar.

Para filtrar los datos del arreglo se debe convertir ese arreglo en un observable:

```
this.http
  .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
  .subscribe((val : any) => {
    // convertir la respuesta `val` en un nuevo observable
    // para poder filtrar el arreglo de objetos
    from(val)
    .pipe(
      take(4)
    ).subscribe(v => console.log('users list', val))
    
  });
```